# Is it possible to change the "width" & "height" attribute on an IMG tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="moviesRotator" id="moviesRotator">
<a>
<img width="431" height="348" alt="" src="img_url1"/>
</a>
<a>
<img width="431" height="348" alt="" src="img_url2"/>
</a>
<a>
<img width="431" height="348" alt="" src="img_url3"/>
</a>
</div>
```

I want to make the image wider, and bigger dynamically. So is it possible to do this?

```
$('.moviesRotat0r.a.img').attr('width', 620)
$('.moviesRotat0r.a.img').attr('height', 380)
```

So is it possible to iterate through all the  tags within the  and change the height and width that way?

What is the correct syntax here?

Please let me know.

many thanks.

Comment: @lanzz this makes sense since one has to prove he has made efforts to search the web and experiment before posting :p

Answer (score 6):

You can do this ... Make sure the source of images are large enough to avoid enlargement artefacts ...

```
$('.moviesRotator img').attr('width', 620).attr('height', 380);
```

Use the container's id instead if available (search is faster)

```
$('#moviesRotator img').attr('width', 620).attr('height', 380);
```

Comment: Note that you should use css instead

Answer (score 3):

The selector would be :

```
$('.moviesRotator > a > img')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is even better, check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/cpeW8/3/

Html sample:

```
<img src='#' width="320" height="240" />
```

jQuery sample:

```
(function($) {
    var imgSelected = $('img');
    console.log('Current width: ' + imgSelected.attr('width') + '; Current height: ' + imgSelected.attr('height'));
    imgSelected.attr({
        width: 400,
        height: 300
    });
    console.log('Current width: ' + imgSelected.attr('width') + '; Current height: ' + imgSelected.attr('height'));
})(jQuery)
```

In your case it will be:

```
$('#moviesRotator img').attr({
    width: 400,
    height: 300
});
```

Comment: nice way of passing an object with the values as a parameter to attr() instead of passing only two parameters. This is better for applying multiple values at the same time.

Comment: Actually , i have tried the following                $('#moviesRotator img').attr({
    width: 600,
    height: 600
});

Comment: I have 3 <img> tags inside "moviesRotator", so I was trying to do that, ('.moviesRotator img').each(function(index){

$(this).attr({
 width: 600,
    height: 600
}
)
}); and on the console in FireBug, it says .each() is not a function very strange!!

Comment: You forgot the $ in front of ('.moviesRotator